# ORA-00922 in procedure that has an update statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I'm getting an error PLS-00103 on the second IF statement in the LOOP.

> [Error] PLS-00103 (17: 13): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of > the following:
>
> . ( * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem then
>      and or || multiset
>    The symbol "then" was substituted f....

Here's the procedure and the columns in the update both contain primary keys so there is no possibility of a null. The role-id column has a NO NULL constraint.

```
create procedure sp_fix_property_role as
-- make sure the role_id contains an offense_party_id 
 cursor curs_property is select p.* 
    from  t_offense o inner join t_property p on p.offense_id = o.offense_id
    where receive_date > to_date('12/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy');

cursor curs_offense_party is select op.* 
    from t_offense_party op inner join t_offense o on o.offense_id = op.offense_id
    where receive_date > to_date('12/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy'); 

begin for cp1 in curs_property loop
    for co1 in curs_offense_party loop
--when property offense = offense party offense
    --and property role <> offense party id    
        if cp1.offense_id = co1.offense_id
            if cp1.role_id <> co1.offense_party_id then
    --then find property role = offense party person
                if cp1.role_id = co1.person_id then
     --replace property role with offense party id
                    update t_property set t_property.role_id = co1.offense_party_id
                        where t_property.property_id = cp1.property_id;
                 end if;
            end if;
         end if;
    end loop; end loop; end sp_fix_property_role;
```

---

This is being compiled in TOAD with 11g client

oaksong

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact text of the error messages you're receiving. And you might want to fix up the declaration of the curs_property cursor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Added "or replace" after CREATE
2. Added a line feed before the two instances of LOOP so it looks like this:

   ```
   for cp1 in curs_property 
   loop
      for co1 in curs_offense_party 
      loop
   ```